# Устранение полосы при скроллинге страницы. Проблемы с Parallax.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, parallax

Использую [Parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) в своем проекте. При скроллинге 
страницы вниз, над фоновым изображением, которое запараллакчено, появляется полоса: [image: Пример проблемы] 
Не знаю важно ли это или нет, но я использую сетку Bootstrap и фоновое изображение реализовано таким образом:

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/BGimage1.jpg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Уточню, что полоса появляется снизу или сверху от "статичного" контента в зависимости от того, куда прокручивается страница - вниз или вверх соответственно. Проверял в Chrome и Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение. Оказывается, в настройках плагина был параметр, который скрывает этот эффект торможения. Параметр называется bleed.

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/BGimage1.jpg" data-bleed="20">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Было такое. Картинку унеси в css и  пропиши ей

```
background: url(images/mybg.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
```

Comment: К сожалению, не вижу возможности таким образом реализовать эффект parallax.